# self.encoding_errors & I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, csv, python-unicode

The below problem is temporarily fixed. I figured out that the input file (csv) has special characters (e.g. Aimí©) that resulted in the error. I now manually change the characters (e.g. Aimí© --> Aime).

Previous question:

I am using `unicodecsv` while writing to a csv file. My program ran smoothly until I encountered the below error. Could someone help?

Code:

```
import unicodecsv as csv
output_csv_write = open(csv_file_name_write,'w')
csv_file_write = csv.writer(output_csv_write, encoding='utf-8')
csv_file_write.writerow([An array of info])
```

First error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: unexpected end of data
```

After seeing the above error, I try to debug by running:

```
    csv_file_write.writerow(['A','B','C'])
```

and I received the second error as below:

```
     84     def writerow(self, row):
     85         return self.writer.writerow(
---> 86                 _stringify_list(row, self.encoding, self.encoding_errors))
     87 
     88     def writerows(self, rows):

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: I don't get that error in Python 2.7.6, unicodecsv  0.14.1.

Comment: @Robᵩ My apology. I just realized that it happened after I encountered another problem. I am modifying my question to provide more details.

Comment: Please provide the shortest **complete** program that demonstrates the error you are having. Since the error is data-dependent, please include a short sample set that causes the error. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: According to the Python 2 [csv docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) files handled by the `csv` module should be opened in binary mode, (on platforms where that makes a difference) and that also applies to `unicodecsv`, since it's a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @Robᵩ Thank you so much for your help! It took me a while to figure out what went wrong with my code. I realized that the input file (csv) has special characters (e.g. Aimí©) that resulted in the error. Temporarily, I am manually changing those characters (e.g. Aimí© --> Aime) to avoid the problem.

Comment: It sounds like your original file was not UTF-8 encoded. You didn't need to change the data to fix your problem

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Could you help advise how I could do it without changing the data? I am very new to web scraping and programming, and I would very appreciate your advice.

Comment: @TommyN you need to provide all your code, the source file (preferably a link to the original so that the encoding is as-is), and the full stack trace of your error

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import unicodecsv as csv

with open(csv_file_name_write, "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, encoding="utf-8")
    writer.writerow(["A", "B", "C"])
```

If that does not solve your problem, unfortunately, I cannot help you because this is working on my machine.

Comment: My original error was `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: unexpected end of data`

Comment: "decode"?? The example is only encoding. Are you sure this is actually the cause of your problem?